# How to write a script for brute force attack on iPhone screen time password. There is a way to get an unlimited attempts

Tags: python, iphone, security, ios16

I've set a Screen Time Passcode with restriction to allow Account Changes (Settings/Screen Time/Content and Privacy Restrictions/Account Changes - Don't Allow). I forget the password and cannot reset it via Apple ID reset.

However, I've found a way to get Unlimited Attempts to guess the Screen Time Passcode. How can I write a script to brute force the Passcode via Settings/General/Transfer and Reset iPhone/Erase All Content and Settings?

I've tried to reset it through Apple ID reset settings, but it didn't work. I tried to use third-party software, however, it all needs to turn off FMI in Account settings and I can't access Account settings because of restriction (Account settings bar is grey and not active).
I tried to use Pinfinder (https://github.com/gwatts/pinfinder), but it didn't work either.

The last try I've made was using iOSResctrictionsBruteForce (https://github.com/thehappydinoa/iOSRestrictionBruteForce). This didn't help due to encrypted data on a backup.

Comment: how much data do you have on your phone? seems like it might be easier to backup everything you can and factory reset it ¯\( ツ )/¯

Comment: It is unavailable, because there is screen time password, which prevents me from doing factory reset

Comment: Sometimes (idk about iPhones but definitely on Android), there is a certain key combo to force reset your phone. I actually had a similar problem a while ago, where the screen time app disconnected from the parent app, so had to hard reset the phone. Would be worth looking into if there is a key to do it

Comment: Method 4 on [this site](https://www.bankmycell.com/blog/how-to-reset-iphone-without-passcode/) says that you can do it with the following (after you have backed the phone up)
- iPhone X, 8 & Newer: Press and hold the Volume up button, then the Volume Down button, and the side button at the same time
- iPhone 7 / 7 Plus: Press and hold the Volume Down and the side button at the same time
- iPhone 6S & older: Press and hold both the Side and Top buttons

Answer (score -2):

I found a way to get unlimited attempts.

So basically you go into the factory reset settings and click yes and everything and when it asks you for the screen time passcode on that screen you can get infinite attempts.

You can bruteforce it from 0 - 9999 which is what I've done.

Don't worry, after the screentime  page theres a final confirmation if you want to factory reset make sure you press cancel!